# why data in django framework is not storing in the database while i have done with all the migrations?

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django I have done everything that was explained in javatpoint (learning website),i have done all the migrations ,i have executed python manage.pymigrate,makemigrations,sqlmigrate appname 0001_initial everything , the form is created successfully  but the data uploading is not storing in the database.
i just want the data (first name and lastname ) to be stored to the employee table and the data to be downloaded as csv file.

```
views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from name.forms import EmployeeForm
from name.models import Employee
import csv



def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                return redirect('/')
            except:
                pass
    else:
        form = EmployeeForm()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})

def getfile(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.csv"'
    employees = Employee.objects.all()
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    for employee in employees:
        writer.writerow([employee.id,employee.first_name,employee.last_name])
    return response





 forms.py

    from django import forms
    from name.models import Employee


    class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Employee
            fields = "__all__"





models.py

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "employee"




script.js
alert("Hello, Welcome to Javatpoint");







index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

style.css
h1{
color:red;
}







urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from name import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('index/', views.index),
    path('csv',views.getfile)

]


 0001_initial.py(after migration)


    from django.db import migrations, models


    class Migration(migrations.Migration):

        initial = True

        dependencies = [
        ]

        operations = [
            migrations.CreateModel(
                name='Employee',
                fields=[
                    ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                    ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
                    ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=30)),
                ],
                options={
                    'db_table': 'employee',
                },
            ),
        ]
```

Comment: your view simply checks if the form is valid and, if it is, redirects - it does not save anything into the database inbetween

Comment: sir can you please help me with code;

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? You need to have code in your view function that saves the form data to the database - something you haven't yet attempted, and which you can find plenty of references for online. In any case, even if I were inclined to simply write it for you (as opposed to help you debug an attempt which doesn't work, which I'd be happy to), I'd need to see the Form and Model code as well as the view.

Comment: sir i have included form and model code above

Comment: thanks - since it's a simple ModelForm then all you should need, just before the redirect, is to put `form.save()`

Comment: @RobinZigmond Please don't post answers as comments.  Doing so bypasses crucial StackExchange moderation systems such as downvotes, and it also deprives you of those sweet sweet answer points.

Comment: @AdamBarnes - sorry, I thought this was accepted practice for very short and simple answers. I'll write it up as an answer when I can get to a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Django ModelForms have a [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method to actually insert the form data into the database.

So you just need to alter part of your view to include this statement, as follows:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            pass
```